# Group of Hodge classes and short exact sequence

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I would like to know if there exists a relation between $ \mathrm{Hdg}_k(X \bigcup Y ) $, $ \mathrm{Hdg}_k(X) $ and $ \mathrm{Hdg}_k( Y) $ ( short exact sequence, or direct sum or something like that ), such that $ \mathrm{Hdg}_k ( X ) = H^{k,k} ( X ) \bigcap H^{2k} ( X , \mathbb{Q} ) $ is the group of Hodge classes.
Can you tell me if you know some references about this subject ?
Thanks a lot.  :-)